# internet explorer 11 Syntax error in regular expression error with javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am receiving a `Syntax error in regular expression` error in Internet Explorer 11 and I have tried the following options:

```
chars = text.split(/(?!$)/u),
chars = text.split(new RegExp("(?!$)", 'u'))
chars = text.split(new RegExp('/(?!$)/', 'u'));
```

I am curious what I am missing here. [insert comment how this works fine in other browsers]

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a regular expression with the unicode flag ("u") which [is not supported by any Internet Explorer <= 11](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_y_and_u_flags).

You can try to use a library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com).