# When using fortawesome, script5017 syntax error occurs in internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, font-awesome, core-js

The console error message is like under this statement

```
script5017 syntax error in regular expression

chunk-vendors.js (96290,5)
```

**chunk-vendors.js**

```
!*** ./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.regexp.constructor.js ***!
...
result = inheritIfRequired(NativeRegExp(pattern, flags), thisIsRegExp ? this : RegExpPrototype, RegExpWrapper); // line 96290
...
```

**main.js**

```
import 'core-js/stable'
import "core-js/es/symbol";
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import 'intersection-observer' // Optional
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
// fontawesome 6.1.1
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

library.add(
  fas,
  far
)
```

I use `BootstrapVue` too. I feel sometimes `BootstrapVue` makes some conflicts with `fortawesome`. Sometimes it is not loaded well when I used `BootstrapVue` with even in chrome. So I added the statement about it in this source

Anyway, I don't know why js isn't loaded by script 5017 error happens. Can this be `core-js` error or `BootstrapVue` error?

I used

`@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types` 6.1.1

`@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome` 2.0.6

`core-js` 3.20.2

`bootstrap` 4.6.1

`bootstrap-vue` 2.21.2

Comment: I found [a similar issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11504#issuecomment-473528760) and from the comments, the error in IE may be caused by using `/u` flag in regex. The [`/u` modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode#browser_compatibility) was only introduced in ECMAScript 6/ES2015, and IE11 only supports ES5 standard. You can investigate deeper to check if it is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Font Awesome 6, which [does not support IE11](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/dig-deeper/browser-support) any more.
You could downgrade to Font Awesome 5, which [does](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/other-topics/browser-support).

Your `package.json` should look something like this:

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.10",
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.36"
  }
}
```

Then update with `yarn` or `npm i`.

Note versions `"core" <1.3` + `*-icons =5.15.4` + `vue-fontawesome <1`, which correspond to "Font Awesome < 6", as far as I could tell.

The `resolutions` part might not be necessary, but I had a hard time convincing yarn to actually downgrade below `1.3.0`, for whatever reason.
You might want to check `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/package.json` to confirm the installed version.

The issue is indeed the [missing support for Unicode RegExes in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735209/internet-explorer-11-syntax-error-in-regular-expression-error-with-javascript-re), which Font Awesome 6 relies on.

I've spent some time trying to make it work with [`@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex) to no success.